# Linking files one solution to another solution is not working-- ASp.net MVC3

Tags: visual-studio, asp.net-mvc-3

I am working on ASP.MVC3 project. I created a base project where I will have all common files / pages like Master Page, Global.asax, Web.Config, Script files, CSS files, and images.  And I have another solution which will contain module related stuff and I am linking common files / pages from first solution with “Add As Link” (Add  Existing Item  Add As Link ) option (I am working with VS.net 2010 IDE).

After linking all the files are coming into second solution and looking fine.
But when I run, the application is not running.  Getting the message enable debut which already there.

when i clilck OK i am getting the error “the operation could not be completed.  Unexpected error”  (i think its expecting the physical file in the second solution location only).
After some R & D I placed the web config and global.asax directly (which is normal) in the second solution then the application started running.  The same case for images / css / script files.
Please let us know the issue what we are doing wrong or is there any other way to share/link files from another solution.
Thanks in Advance.

Answer (score 0):

You're probably better off doing it the other way around - create a website project and link your libraries / base classes to your project by adding a reference to them.  This way you add all your images, css files etc direct into the website.

That's the more usual way of doing it in my experience, hope it helps.

Comment: Thank you very much for your response.  
Yeah, this way already we are doing and the application is working fine.  In this problem  is only we can reference server side code not Views / CSS files / Script.  What i am expecting is when i change something in the Base solution in View/script,… it has to reflect in the client solution.  If we add View / Script files directly to client solution the developer need to get the latest files from base solution copy into client solution manually which i want to avoid.
Thanks in Advance

Comment: what do you mean by the "client solution"?  surely the "client" refers to the web browser...?  Do you mean that your resources such as script files need to be available somewhere other than your website?

Comment: Here client solution means a separate solution not web browser.  For more clarity the solution where I am linking the files from base solution.  Suppose I have three solutions S1(Base), S2, S3.  S1 will have all the common files Views/Scripts/CSSs and I want to share/link those files into S2, S3 solutions. So when I change something in A that change needs to reflect in S2, S3 automatically. I heard this can be achieved with TFS/VSTS feature “Add as Link” option.  Please let me know if you need any additional info.
Thanks in Advance.

Comment: Sounds painful... copy and pasting the files will probably be the most straight-forward solution :)

Answer (score 0):

The reason it doesn't work is because the linked files aren't copied to your working directory. To make your solution work you simply publish it to some other folder and it would re-create the site with copies of all linked files. There's no need to re-organize your solution as it would deploy all linked files once you publish it.